# Blazor Server "Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }."

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-6.0

I started experiencing this issue with Visual Studio 2019 after upgrading from dotnet 6.0-Preview6 to 6.0-Preview7. There appears to be a race condition when running my app.

I've created a new Blazor Server app in Visual Studio. When I start debugging, my browser launches, but then I get an InvalidOperationException. I've made no changes to the project out of the box.

```
Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }.
```

Full Stack Trace

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DynamicPageEndpointMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

This happens about 4/5 times I try to debug. Every once in a while, it works correctly. This issue is not related to my current project, as I am seeing the same behavior in other Blazor Server apps.

If I use Visual Studio 2022 Preview, my app runs properly every time.

I also have 100% success rate when starting my app with `dotnet watch run`.

I've tried repairing my dotnet 6.0-Preview7 installation, but I can't seem to get around this.

Comment: Have you any packages to upgrade, using preview flag checked ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that in my post.Yes, I did update all packages with the flag checked.

Comment: Have you changed the position of your "Pages" folder?

Comment: Nope, this happens right out of the box for me. The only change I made as upgrading the packages. (It didn't work before, or after upgrading).

Comment: VS2019 plain or VS2019 Preview?  Are you sure Preview7 is supported for your VS?

Comment: I'm seeing this today - was fine in Preview-7, but broke when I upgraded to RC1. Did you get anywhere with it? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36535 Happening to me on MacOS. Edit: Looks like there's a potential fix in that issue.

Comment: I didn't get anywhere with it. I just resolved myself to waiting for the next release. Thanks for posting the workaround.

Comment: I ran into this issue today and cleaning the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what I did was close the entire solution, close the VS, go to your project folder and rename the ".vs" folder to something else, open your solution again, let VS recreate the .vs folder and its contents, everything works fine now.

What happen was I tried to simulate Virtualize millions of records on my components and I close my browser while it is still loading.

Probably due to incomplete process in memory and cause some files in .vs corrupted.

Rename old .vs folder in case there is any needed files to be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today running Blazor Server on dotnet 6.0. Restarting VS didn't work for me, but going to the build toolbar and clicking "rebuild solution" to delete and regenerate all the intermediate and output files resolved it right away.

Following the advice from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 to clean solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm two years late, but I faced this problem and searched and discovered the following line of code that fixed it.
You should add it to your `Program.cs` file.

```
builder.Services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options => options.RootDirectory = "/Pages");
```